# Uboot terminate standalone application

Tags: assembly, bootloader, u-boot, bare-metal

I have a little problem terminating a standalone application which is run through uboot.I am working on TI's omap5 based evaluation board.Uboot is working fine , I have a simple program which I can upload through uboot's command prompt using loady and execute it using go [loadaddr].

The problem is after the program runs and displays a string of characters,it just hangs there.
I have to manually reset the board to boot it up and continue working with uboot.The startup assembly code i'm using is this

```
.global _Start
_Start:
LDR sp, = sp_top
BL my_init
mov pc,r14
```

Basically i just want to return to the command prompt after the execution of my program

Edit:

code I'm running

```
#define UART3_addr       0x48020000 //UART Port Address
volatile unsigned char * const UART_PTR = (unsigned char *)UART3_addr;

int my_init() 
{

display ("Testing");
return 0;
}


void display(const char *string)
{
while(*string != '\0'){
    *UART_PTR = *string;
    string++;
}
}
```

Comment: You don't give us a lot of details but, maybe, the program you start with U-Boot never returns. Could you show the program ?

Comment: I added the code...I have also tried stripping everything and just using a return 0; call inside my_init() function....

Comment: ... Maybe your toolchain (ABI?); but I think you are using the good one because your program runs. It could be great if you could read into the stack and debug for this kind of bug....

Comment: *"i just want to return to the command prompt"* -- Then you have to preserve the stack and return address that U-Boot hands to your "program".  Your start code seems to not do that.  Your standalone "program" is treated as a procedure by U-Boot, not as an executable in a real OS.